# Visual Studion 2012 - Showing Gray Full Window - Unable to debug

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am having form based application.
Once I start debug and set the break point, it is showing GRAY out hence unable to debug. 
I have visual studio version as 2012 - Update 5. 
The code is at back side and it was overlapped 
Please check the below screen shot.
[image: The code is at back side and it was overlapped]

Comment: Could it be defaulting to some strange window layout when you debug? What happens if you try 'Reset Window Layout' on the WINDOW menu?

Comment: Thanks @LogicalFlaps, I manage to reset the settings and it solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.. Finally I have done reset of all settings in TOOLS->IMPORT & EXPORT Settings -> Reset all settings. 
This solved it.